# Where should I add an (url encoded) querystring in my named route?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

In my asp.net-mvc ontroller I accept a bunch of form field values and from those create a string the Lucene library understands.
Then I want to redirect to a get method that will show results depending on this lucene string.

The lucene string is in the pattern {fieldName1:value1 fieldName2:value2 ...}

my Global.asax has the following entry for the redirect target:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AdvancedSearch",
    "AdvancedSearch.mvc/{displayType}/luceneString",
    new { controller = "Search", action = "AdvancedSearch",
          displayType = "chip", luceneString = "" }
);
```

So my controller catches the post, creates the luceneString and does the following:

```
return RedirectToRoute("AdvancedSearch", new
    {
        Controller = "Search",
        action = "AdvancedSearch",            
        displayType = "chip",
        queryString = Url.Encode("company:test name:testname")
     });
```

This gives me a 500: bad request.
Even with one parameter it doesn't work. Even with the ":" it doesn't work.
I tried:

- AdvancedSearch.mvc/chip/company%3Atest+name%3AtestName
- AdvancedSearch.mvc/chip/company:test+name:testName
- AdvancedSearch.mvc/chip/company:test
- AdvancedSearch.mvc/chip/company%3Atest

It only works if I change this url to take the queryString in the format of

```
AdvancedSearch.mvc/chip?q=company%3Atest+name%3AtestName
```

What should I do to get the encoding right without resorting to "?q="
If I have to use the querystring, how can I define such a thing in the route table? How do I go about to call redirect to it?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but it sounds like you're trying to get asp-mvc to do something it's not supposed to.  Routes are supposed to be a RESTful way of replacing query strings.  I understand that Lucene may require it, but whatever solution you come up with will likely be a perma-hack.

Comment: How so? If I understand right, my URL will be RESTfull. A get request to a URL will always return the same page. No session or whatsoever is required. It's just that the last part of my URL contains a query string.

Comment: My Post requests will redirect to a GET request. They will still be stateless. Does the fact that the last part of my URL is a lucene string make it RESTless?

Comment: Michael, that is just wrong. Routes are ways of handling a URI, which may have a query. REST does not mean "no query strings." URIs contain a resource (expressed within the route) and information about how to display the resource (the query). See the URI RFC for details.

Comment: Statelessness is an important part of REST, but so is uniformity. Routes and query strings both provide a consistent way of conveying state. Both together area non-uniform solution. --- more ---

Comment: Query strings have been used to convey state on top of physical location URLs. Routes remove the physical location limitation, allowing state to be conveyed in path. Neither is superior, but mixing them, hurts the uniformity constraint.

Comment: Routing is a way of interpreting the resource portion of a URI. It would be incorrect, by definition, to put non-resource information in the resource. Both resources and queries are part of URIs; again, read the RFC. Whether a given URI is RESTful has *nothing* to do with how you generate/read it.

Comment: RFC: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

Comment: Point taken. I'm arguing about the hackiness of going against the grain of a framework. It's a proper use of URI, yes. QueryStrings are RESTful, yes. Combining QueryStrings and routes is not RESTful. ASP-MVC seeks to be RESTful. Combining QueryString and routes works against the grain.

Comment: Again, I completely disagree that using queries is "going against the grain" of either ASP.NET MVC or Routing. But a full explanation of why  (1) won't fit here and (2) is off-topic. I'll blog it later.

Comment: Although I do agree with Craig, I would certainly be interested in seeing Michael's point. Sadly, 300 char comments are not the optimal way to do so. If you blog about it, please link here.

Comment: @Craig: Appart from your sentiment of working against the framework's intent by using a querystring, how would you create a URI that has about 10 parameters of which 7 are optional? ...

Comment: At first I interpreted the string as a single parameter, so I wanted to pass it on. But apparantly, spaces, double points and other characters are impossible (encoded or not encoded) to pass as a regular part of a URI in asp.net-mvc

Comment: boris, here is the requested blog link: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/03/18/38085/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your MapRoute should contain nothing regarding the query string. Routes contain the resource portion of the URI only; they do not include the query.

Second, you don't need to encode the query string; ActionLink/RouteLink/etc. will do that for you. When you are building an HREF, any tokens not contained in the route will become encoded query string parameters automatically.

Remove:

```
/luceneString
```

...from your route.

Change your code to:

```
return RedirectToRoute("AdvancedSearch", new
{
    Controller = "Search",
    action = "AdvancedSearch",            
    displayType = "chip",
    q = "company:test name:testname"
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But why can't my luceneString be part of the url?  How will this influence caching? Is caching dependant on the querystring too?

Comment: If you want it in the resource portion of the URI, it's part of the route. If you want it in the query string portion of the URI, it is not part of the route. Generally, caching is dependent on the whole URI, including the query string, but it depends what sort of caching you're asking about.

Comment: In IIS6, no; IIS 7, yes: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/204/http-response-cache/ If you actually meant the ASP.NET cache, it depends on your VaryByParam: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcacheparameters.varybyparam.aspx

Comment: I would firstly want IIS to worry about if possible so I don't have to. But indeed I can always create a custom varyby if I want.